# Java Swing applications not opening in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have been having some major issues when I try to run a new Swing application. I am using **NetBeans 8.1**, **JDK version 1.8** and **OS Windows 10**.

So every time I try to open a new Swing project (doesn't matter if it's just the app project or an EA) and I run it, *NetBeans deploys it correctly but the Swing window doesn't open* and in the status bar of NetBeans *it just shows running*. I wait for several minutes and then I have to stop the build because nothing happens. When I faced this situation before I uninstalled NetBeans and Java and reinstall them, and it's fixed. But I don't want to uninstall and install everything again when I want to open a new project. I am right now learning about Swing. If that project has a Web version, it works fine. I've put my laptop on Airplane mode so WiFi is disabled (a friend told me to do this) but with no luck.

So this is my IDE and it says "Running" in the status bar when I run the project using the Swing project, but the application window is not opened

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIJkd.png)

Comment: it's "Applications", sorry about the typo

Comment: What do you mean by `open a new Swing project` and `NetBeans deploys it correctly`?

Comment: I have an Enterprise Application (Java EE) project and I created a Enterprise Application Client where I created my Swing files. When I run the application, Netbeans doesn't show any error and in the status bar it says "running" but the application window never show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should debug this application, maybe one line code is error or not complete, ... can stop your application. This status bar show is running maybe your application not dispose then it still running

Comment: I've added a message "I am in main" in my main class and I put a breakpoint in that message, but when I debug the application it doesn't reach that message, it seems my main class is not being run. My web application works just fine but my Swing application is the main problem. I've checked my main class file in the Swing project and it's pointing to the file where my main() is.

Comment: Do you debug this class or application? If you debug your application, you should check which the class is main class of this application by right click on your project, choose properties, then click run and see the main class of application is correct class you add this message?

Comment: Yes, I double checked it right away and it is my Java class that contains the main method.

Comment: If you run correct class, you should check the package in first line of this class. Maybe missing it to make your problem.